# How to trigger action after many-to-many association has been destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails 4 app I have the following models:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many  :allocations
  has_many  :payments, :through   => :allocations

end
```

---

```
class Allocation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :payment

end
```

---

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many    :allocations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many    :invoices,    :through => :allocations

  after_save    :update_invoices
  after_destroy :update_invoices # won't work

  private

  def update_invoices
    invoices.each do |invoice|
      invoice.save
    end
  end

end
```

---

The problem is that I need to update an `invoice` when one of its `payments` gets destroyed.

The `update_invoices` callback above obviously can't ever get triggered because at the time it gets called the connection with the `invoice` has already been destroyed.

So how can this be done?

Right now, I am doing this in my `PaymentsController`:

```
def destroy
  @payment.destroy
  current_user.invoices.each do |invoice|
    invoice.save
  end
  ...
end
```

However, this is very expensive of course because it goes through each and every `invoice` that a `user` has.

What might be a better alternative to this?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to save on the invoice? the code above doesnt seem to dirty an invoice

Comment: @blotto: Lots of things. For example the `outstanding_amount` and `payment_status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the associated allocation is also destroyed when destroying the payment.  If you move the invoice updating to the Allocation model instead it will work as intended.

```
class Allocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :payment

  after_destroy :update_invoice

  def update_invoice
    if destroyed?
      invoice.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Here's a Rails 4.1 test project with tests for this:

https://github.com/infused/update_parent_after_destroy

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to grab the invoices before destroying the payment instance. Its add a bit more logic to the Controller however, but this is where the intent of both actions ( destroy payment and update invoices ) originate.  It also reduces the iteration to just those invoices affected by the destroyed payment.

```
 def destroy
   invoices = @payment.invoices
   @payment.destroy
   invoices.each do |invoice|
     invoice.save
   end
   ...
 end
```

Presumably you are overriding the `save` method of the Invoice model ( or have a callback on that as well), though I would choose a more explicit method for this intent.  For example, `removed_payment` could be a method to handle this specific scenario and update the appropriate attributes - `outstanding_amount` and `payment_status`, etc.

```
 def destroy
   invoices = @payment.invoices
   @payment.destroy
   invoices.map(&:removed_payment)
   ...
 end
```

Comment: It's strange. I can't get any of your suggestions to work. Is it possible that the `invoices` variable gets somehow *changed* when `@payment` gets destroyed? It still works when I use `current_user.invoices`, though.

Comment: try renaming `invoices` in example above.  though i doubt its colliding - maybe call it `affected_invoices`.  try also to output to console to ensure the payment indeed has any invoices.  for example `p affected_invoices.count`

Comment: I got it. In my initial post I embezzled a `:dependent => :destroy` call in the `Payment` model. So when `@payment` is destroyed, there's no more connection between payments and invoices and the invoices stored in the variable `invoices` can't be accessed any more. Sorry, I should have included that line in my first post. Is there an alternative approach to yours?